# How to compute a given formula as a string parameter in a JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following HTML:

```html
<input name="20152" class="valid-decimal" id="20152" type="text" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" data-fieldname="Height">
<input name="20153" class="valid-decimal" id="20152" type="text" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" data-fieldname="Weight">
<input name="20155" id="testcompute" type="text" maxlength="4000" data-fieldname="BMI" placeholder="Result">
<button type="button" id="btnCalculate" onclick="FillAndSubmit('@control.OptionList')">Calculate</button>
```

And the Javascript function which is being called on the Button click is:

```
function FillAndSubmit(formula) {
    formulaArray = formula.split(" "); //if the passed formula is 10 * ( Height + Weight ), formulaArray items are- 10,(,Height,+,Weight,) 
    for(var item in formulaArray)
    {
        //need to iterate through each item;re-construct the formula so //that we can calculate
    }
    //calculate the value and set in the data-fieldname="BMI" textbox
    $("input[data-fieldname='BMI']").val(CF); //CF is the constructed formula in //the above loop
```

So basically,

1. Each item in the formula are set apart by a space
2. There are three different types of items:

   1. Parenthesis-( or )
   2. Number
      3.Operator(+,-,*,/)
   3. ControlName-Here Height and Weight are the data-fieldnames of the     different text boxes.

Any help will be highly appretiated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you want to use parenthesis and `*` before `+` etc you'll probably need to build some kind of tree structure representing your formula, then calculate based on that

Answer (score 0):

You Would do something along the lines of this.

```
var operatorList = [];

    operatorList.push(["times","*",timesit]);
    operatorList.push(["add","+",addit]);

function timesit(width, height){return (width * height);}
function addit(width, height){return (width + height);}

var opString = "*";
var intWidth = 20;
var intHeight = 30;

var result;
for(var i in operatorList){
    if(opString === operatorList[i][1]){
        result = operatorList[i][2](intWidth, intHeight);
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

What your doing here is adding functions to an array and then collecting and  executing the right function by comparing opString to the second item in the array(NOTE arrays count from 0).